# How to allocate a Python (Django) project in a ready and configured server? (Apache, MySQL, Python, Django OK)

Tags: python, mysql, django, apache

I have a ready and fully configured server. Python, Django, Apache, MySQL, all OK.

I would like to replicate an existing project on this server for testing. The files and database are already replicated, however, to access the project folder via browser it back directories without interpreting the code in Python, as below:

```
cgi-bin/
robots.txt
wsgi.py
Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.9 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at test.xxxxxx.com.br Port 80
```

Comment: What does "ready and fully configured" mean? Are you already running a Django project on this server? How is it configured?

Comment: Have you read the Django documentation for deploying to mod_wsgi? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thank you @GrahamDumpleton.
That is the exactly what I'm looking for.